# dynamic script not parsing correctly

Tags: sql-server

I basically trying to create a dynamic sql script that should do the following

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('FinData2000_1') AND NAME = 'idx_FinData2000_1')
            drop  index idx_FinData2000_1 on FinData2000_1
```

Following is the dynamic script that is not parsing

```
SET @sql = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('
            + @tableName + '') AND NAME =  'idx_' + @tableName + '
            drop  index' + @tableName + '.idx_' + @tableName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic string is not correct, try:

```
SET @sql = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('''
            + @tableName + ''') AND NAME =  ''idx_' + @tableName + ''' 
            drop  index idx_' + @tableName + ' ON ' + @tableName;
```

**Output: print(@SQL):**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('FinData2000_1') AND NAME =  'idx_FinData2000_1' 
            drop  index idx_FinData2000_1 ON FinData2000_1
```

Comment: I think you need a space after `drop  index'` as well, so it should be `drop  index '` And this doesn't need 3 single quotes after it, `''idx_'''`, only 1.

Comment: This is what i get IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('FinData2000_1') AND NAME =  'idx_'FinData2000_1
            drop  index FinData2000_1.idx_FinData2000_1

Comment: @Tom, I just edited it around `FinData2000`, check it :)

Comment: now i get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'drop'.  this is the output  if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('FinData2000_1') AND NAME =  'idx_FinData2000_1' 
            drop index FinData2000_1.idx_FinData2000_1

Comment: Can you do drop index tablename.indexname. I thought it should be drop index indexname on tablename

Comment: There is bracket missing after name =

Comment: IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('FinData2000_1') AND NAME =  'idx_FinData2000_1' 
            drop  index idx_FinData2000_1 ON FinData2000_1

Comment: I have resolved it.Once you do it from your side shall mark your answer

Comment: @Tom, you mean the bracket around the table name? it can be queried without bracket, if you meant so.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic query

```
declare @tablename varchar(100) = 'tablename'
declare @indexname varchar (100) = 'indexname'
declare @query varchar(max) = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('+@tablename+') AND NAME = '+@indexname+') 
            drop  index '+@indexname+' on '+@tablename+''
```

works for any table and index name you pass